# Django Template - use same block twice with different variables

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a block called `car_table` and two kind of cars: blue and red. I want a template with two tables, one for the red cars and one for the blue cars, but I want to use just the 'general' block `car_table`.

in `base_template.html` I define the headers and general stuff

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    blablabla...

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

</html>
```

here is `cars_table.html`

```
{% extends base_template.html %}
{% block content %}

    blablabla...

    {% block table %}
    ...
        {% for car in cars %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ car.name }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Now, I want a page with two tables: blue cars and red cars, using just the code in `cars_table`

Comment: how about having one template (`both_tables.html`) and the template with the actual table would be included (via `{% include car_table.html %}`) twice, each for one colour of cars, instead of extending the base template

Comment: How can I specify the variables on which perform the loops? One should be on  red_cars and the other on  blue_cars, instead in car_table.html I have only a loop on cars.

Comment: `{% with red_cars as cars_for_loop %} {% include car_table.html %}{% endwith %}`

Answer (score 1):

reposting the comments: How about having one template (eg. `both_tables.html`) and the template with the actual table would be included (via `{% include %}`) twice, each for one colour of cars, instead of extending the base template:

`both_tables.html`:

```
{% with red_cars as cars %}
    {% include car_table.html %}
{% endwith %}

{% with blue_cars as cars %}
    {% include car_table.html %}
{% endwith %}
```

`car_table.html`:

```
{% for car in cars %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ car.name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```